# How to upload file to restful api kotlin

Tags: file, http, kotlin, okhttp

Hi I am just wondering if I am doing something wrong when trying to upload this zip file via kotlin. My rest API already works for uploading a zip file (I checked with curl). However, I cannot make kotlin upload the file. It seems to rename the .zip file to "file" and then the file loses its contents.

```
fun uploadFile(extension: String, f: File){
    print(f.path)
    val response = khttp.post(url = this.url + extension,
           files = listOf(FileLike("file", File(f.path)))
    )
    print(response.text)
}
```

I also tried it with passing in the file object itself where File(f.path) is.
Nothing I seem to do works. I am running kotlin and the server is running on ubuntu. I do not know if this causes problems with directories.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: Was not getting an error, it was simply corrupting the file. I later changed how I was interacting with the file on the REST api end to better suit kotlin, it is weird it does not follow typical http requests layout seemingly.

Comment: Have you tried to set the headers for content type?  in the case: application/zip, application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [kohttp](https://github.com/rybalkinsd/kohttp#upload-files) file upload DSL (since version 0.8.0)

```
val response = upload {
    url( your destination url )
    file( file or file uri )
}
```

or an extension function

```
val response = file.upload( destination string or url )
```